# PHP : foreach warning

Tags: php, foreach, warnings

I'am executing code :

```
<?php
$input="ABC123";
$splits = chunk_split($input,2,"");
foreach($splits as $split)
{
$split = strrev($split);
$input = $input . $split;
}
?>
```

And output that i want is :

```
BA1C32
```

But it gaves me Warning.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/WOOOOOOOOHOOOOOOOO/domains/badhamburgers.com/public_html/index.php on line 4
```

Comment: You can start by doing `print_r($splits)`

Comment: chuck_split return a string, you can't do a foreach on a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`chunk_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) doesn't return an array but rather a part of the string.

You should use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) instead:

```
$input="ABC123";
$splits = str_split($input, 2);
```

And don't forget to reset your `$input` before the loop, else it will contain the old data aswell.

Comment: don't forget to reset your input or change your variable name.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php returns a string, not an array. You could use str_split instead:

```
$input = "ABC123";
$splits = str_split( $input, 2 );
$output = "";
foreach( $splits as $split ){
   $split = strrev($split);
   $output .= $split;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for chunk_split mentions clearly, http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php chunk split returns a string.

foreach expects an array as first argument.